# QGIS panning with setExtent() eventually causes the map canvas to stop loading

Tags: pyqgis

I have written a python script to automatically scroll/pan across the map canvas along a specified path. The script is based off a thread that emits a signal to a handler that does this:

```
def setLocation(self, pt):
    iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(QgsRectangle(pt, pt))
    #iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

This seems to work for a while, the canvas is scrolled along the path. Except that the satellite imagery tiles that I am using for a background map stop loading sometimes and do not start loading again until I pause the thread (stop emitting the signal).

A similar thing happens when I pan across the canvas manually using the keyboard, so I guess this is typical behavior. I am wondering if there is some way that I can detect that the tiles are not loaded completely and then pause execution until things have caught up?